# Probability of choosing inferior goods

Tags: probability

Suppose there are 12 goods in total, among which 3 are inferior goods and the others are normal goods.

Now choose 5 goods randomly. What's the probability of having 2 inferior goods among the 5?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You have a higher chance of getting an answer if you show that you made some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total cases to choose $5$ objects=$$12\choose 5$$

Total ways to choose $2$ inferior=$$3\choose 2$$

Total ways to choose $3$ normal goods=$$9\choose 3$$

Probability=$$\frac{{3\choose 2}\times {9\choose 3}}{12\choose 5}$$
$$=\frac{7}{22}$$

Comment: Always love to help